# XMLAGG throwing ORA-1489 - can't figure out why

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation

I have a requirement to concatenate 3 columns from a table, separated by semicolons.  After researching, I decided to go with xmlagg and getclobval() - it worked fine until early this week, when it began throwing the ORA-1489 - result of string concatenation is too long.  I used xmlagg and getclobval() to specifically avoid this.  At this time, I am still trying to hunt down the offending row, but I would appreciate someone making sure my code is sound.  Thank you!

```
select id, 
   rtrim(extract(xmlagg(xmlelement(e, col1 || ';  ' || col2 || ';  ' || col3 || '; ')), 
           '/E/text()').getclobval(), chr(13)) AS concat_field from schema.table group by id
```

Comment: please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concatenation is throwing error if length of col1+col2+col3+separators > 4000 . `col1 || ';  ' || col2 || ';  ' || col3 || '; '`
Solution: `to_clob`

```
select id, 
   rtrim(extract(xmlagg(xmlelement(e, to_clob(col1) || ';  ' || col2 || ';  ' || col3 || '; ')), 
           '/E/text()').getclobval(), chr(13)) AS concat_field from schema.table group by id
```